# Automated workbook that creates new data everytime it refreshes

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

My coworker showed me an automated workbook that everytime you put a new line in a worksheet and press refresh on the data guide, new lines are placed on another worksheet. It is a budget workbook and for every new person you add, it creates this person's line for the amount of months they are active in the company.

There are no macros or code on VBA and I couldn't find any code or connection to Power Query.
Does anyone have any idea of where that came from and how can I replicate it? It is a very heavy workbook and we need a new one for the new budget year.

Comment: What is the "data guide" ?

Comment: Power BI maybe? Or maybe you mean "Excel data types: Stocks and geography"? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-data-types-stocks-and-geography-61a33056-9935-484f-8ac8-f1a89e210877

Comment: Ask your coworker? Or do some general research otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it was code (Macro).

Before the introduction of VBA (Visual Basic for Applications), older versions of Excel used a macro language called "XLM" or "Excel 4.0 Macro Language." XLM was used in versions of Excel such as Excel 4.0 and earlier. It was a more limited form of macro programming compared to VBA, but it still allowed automation and scripting of tasks within Excel. With the introduction of VBA, XLM was gradually phased out and replaced by the more powerful VBA system.

Comment: There is no code, i looked for it in the developer page

Comment: If there is any code you will most likely find it as 'Code behind sheet' or behind the ThisWorkbook object in the Project Explorer (Alt+F11). Where all event triggers will be found - like Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If the extension of the file name is .xlm - you should look for the hidden sheets.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'Data guide' is a Excel Add inn file (.XLAM) you should be able to find the code for it in the Project Explorer. These type of automation objects is still supported, but not that easy to install anymore.

Explained here how to install (and where you can find what is alraedy there)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reuU2zUsEPM